# Anyone ever install a different Android OS on the Nabi 2?

Tags: custom-roms

The Nabi 2 has some messed-up permissions and controls on it. I need to install another OS on it and my nephew will use it. He likes our Kindle Fire better because you can watch YouTube and Netflix a lot easier. The parental controls were a good idea, but this is **way** too much.

p.s., I kind of want to install plain old Android straight from Google.

Comment: Please take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) to find a fitting ROM. Installation instructions do usually ship along with it.

Comment: Izzy, i dont know what a rom is in this sort of thing. i know of one in referrence to a BIOS for the laptop and desktop. and a rom that people play old video games with. Im looking for an answer to my situation from someone who may have done it, or found a tutorial or video on it.

Comment: ROMs in this context are "firmware images" (see the [rom tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info) for details), so that's what you will need to "install the OS" (see also: [rom-flashing](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info)).